# Command section syntax in .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: gitlab

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file :

```yml
stages:
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=192.168.123.178:5050"]
      
  script:
    - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY "
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://192.168.123.178
```

How can I declare the insecure registry in the deploy stage like I did in the publish stage? I'm always getting syntax errors.

### Edit

It erros out at the deploy stage when executing

```bash
$ ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY "
```

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://[MASKED]:5050/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

I know this is due to the unsecure registry I want it to use.
I then tried to add the unsecure registry declaration in the deploy stage as shown below:

```yml
...
deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY "
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://192.168.123.178
  command: ["--insecure-registry=192.168.123.178:5050"]
```

but this is a YAML syntax error.

Comment: What are the exact errors you get? (Include these in the question!)

Comment: @Kusalananda I made an edit

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply exchange http://192.168.123.178:5050 for $CI_REGISTRY?